# Glyphicon Button onlick toggle table

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, glyphicons

http://jsfiddle.net/LZoesch/xovrr3uo/

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <form method="POST" action="">
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm pull left" name="reset"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-stats"></span>

            </button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm pull-right" name="reset"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span>

            </button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
<table class="table2">
    <div id="chartCanvas" style="padding-left:5px;">
                <canvas id="canvas" style="width:98%;height:500px;"></canvas>
        <br>
    </div>
    </tbody>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      script goes here for chart.js
    </script>

</table>
```

Trying to get the glyphicon to toggle on/off for table "table2"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'table2' table tags are inappropriate. Table should have row and cell elements inside the table.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>{{DATA}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

As per the above syntax, add the content inside the cell .

Now use the jsfiddle link [click here](http://jsfiddle.net/mvamsianil/xovrr3uo/7/) to get the JQuery code on how to toggle the table.

Js fiddle code:

```
$(".glyphicon-stats").on('click', function () {
$('.table2').toggle();
```

});

### Let me know if any other help is needed.

Update jsfiddle link
http://jsfiddle.net/mvamsianil/xovrr3uo/8/

Comment: its also a snippet from my actual site.

Comment: Its just an example. you can infact use the actual glyphicon to get the same behaviour.

Comment: How do I go about doing that?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mvamsianil/xovrr3uo/8/
I've added Id to the button, if it doesn't disturb your working style.

Comment: Ahhh I see. Thank you :)

Comment: No problem, Happy coding. :)

Comment: <table class="table2" style="display:none">

Comment: Hmm, but I can get it to work on the fiddle.. http://jsfiddle.net/LZoesch/xovrr3uo/9/

Comment: I have the code in, but now it wont show the jquery. it keeps it hidden?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90289/discussion-between-vamsi-and-lzoesch).